# What is the Location of NS2 Folder?

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I already install the NS2 simulator from `CLI` and I need to know where the simulator was installed. In other words, I need to know the location of the NS2 folder due to make some changes to its files.

Comment: Try `sudo find / -iname "*NS2*"`

Comment: I tried  (find  . -name "NS2*")   but there is nothing.

Comment: How did you install it? If by a package manager (`apt`, `apt-get`, `dpkg`), see https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/ns2/filelist (for `bionic` on `amd64` YMMV)